# Leonardo serial comunication

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I wrote this sample sketch to test serial communication with Arduino Leonardo (using Arduino IDE 1.0.5 on Windows 7):

```
int delayTime = 10000;
long lastExec = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
}

void loop()
{
  long t = millis();
  if (t - lastExec >= delayTime) {
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
      Serial.println('Hello world');
    }  
    lastExec = t;
  }
}
```

The serial port selected seems working because the sketch uploads correctly.

However I didn't get anything in the serial monitor window. Why?

Comment: It should work if you send something to it.  But then every time Serial.available() will be non-zero -- which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to send a character to the Arduino.

Because you have `if(Serial.available() > 0)`, the Arduino won't `Serial.println("Hello World");` unless there is something in the `Serial buffer`.

You may also want to reduce the `delayTime` which is very long.

In conclusion, you can try this by typing something in your Serial Monitor:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    Serial.println('Hello world');
  }  
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score -3):

Does help to have `"Hello world"`, not `'Hello world'`.